# Should I call super.initState at the end or at the beginning?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am confused as to where to call the `super.initSate()` in Flutter? In some code examples, it's called at the beginning and in others at the end. Is there a difference?

I have tried to google this but haven't found any explanation on the position of this function call.

Which one is correct?

```dart
void initState() {
  super.initState();    
  //DO OTHER STUFF
}
```

or

```dart
void initState() {    
  //DO OTHER STUFF
  super.initState();    
}
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

### It does matter for `mixin`s (and because of that *for you* as well)

It is a **paradigm** in the Flutter framework to call the super method when overriding lifecycle methods in a `State`. This is why even [`deactivate`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/6b93efdd857d2acb54b61dfbf63c24540d3ccb63/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L872) has a [`mustCallSuper` annotation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/meta/mustCallSuper-constant.html).
*Additionally*, some `mixin`s expect that you call the super methods of those lifecycle methods at a particular point in the function.

This means that you should follow the documentation and call `super.dispose` **at the end** of your `dispose` method because `mixin`s on `State` in the framework expect that this is the case.
For example: [`TickerProviderStateMixin`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TickerProviderStateMixin-mixin.html) and [`SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin-mixin.html) [assert](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/fb33b7a1b86aacae45145e40f7946a4de62e3e9a/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart#L183) `super.dispose` at the end:

> All Tickers must [..] be disposed before calling super.dispose().

Another example: [`AutomaticKeepAliveMixin`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/fb33b7a1b86aacae45145e40f7946a4de62e3e9a/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/automatic_keep_alive.dart#L344) executes logic in `initState` and `dispose`.

### Conclusion

[Start your `initState` with `super.initState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) and [end your `dispose` with `super.dispose`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html) if you want to be on the easy and safe side adding `mixin`s to your `State`.
Furthermore, follow the documentation for other lifecycle methods (any method you overwrite in `State`) because the framework will expect that you call the super methods as described in the documentation.

Thus, the following is what you should do:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();    
  // DO YOUR STUFF
}

@override
void dispose() {
  // DO YOUR STUFF
  super.dispose();
}
```

However, it does not *really* matter for `State`, which I will explain in the following and even for mixins, it only matters for assertions judging from what I could find - so it would not affect your production app.

### It does not matter for `State`

I think that the previous two answers from [Pablo Barrera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11938462/) and [CopsOnRoad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6618622) are *misleading* because the truth of the matter is that it really does not matter and you do not need to look far.

The only actions that [`super.initState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) and [`super.dispose`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html) take in the `State` class itself are **assertions** and since `assert`-statements are only evaluated in *debug mode*, it does not matter at all once build your app, i.e. in production mode.

---

In the following, I will guide you through what `super.initState` and `super.dispose` do in `State`, which is all the code that will be executed when you have no additional mixins.

#### `initState`

Let us look exactly what code is executed in `super.initState` first ([source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/fb33b7a1b86aacae45145e40f7946a4de62e3e9a/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L1017)):

```dart
@protected
@mustCallSuper
void initState() {
  assert(_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created);
}
```

As you can see, there is only a lifecycle assertion and the purpose of it is to ensure that your widget works correctly. So as long as you call `super.initState` **somewhere** in your own `initState`, you will see an `AssertionError` if your widget is not working as intended. It does not matter if you took some prior action because the `assert` is only meant to report that something in your code is wrong anyway and you will see that even if you call `super.initState` at the very end of your method.

#### `dispose`

The `dispose` method is analogous ([source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/fb33b7a1b86aacae45145e40f7946a4de62e3e9a/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L1209)):

```dart
@protected
@mustCallSuper
void dispose() {
  assert(_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.ready);
  assert(() {
    _debugLifecycleState = _StateLifecycle.defunct;
    return true;
  }());
}
```

As you can see, it also only contains assertions that handle **debug** lifecycle checking. The second `assert` here is a nice trick because it ensures that the `_debugLifecycleState` is only changed in debug mode (as `assert`-statements are only executed in debug mode).
This means that as long as you call `super.dispose` *somewhere* in your own method, you will not lose any value without mixins adding additional functionality.

Comment: Flutter official docs aren't very good :( thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, would you also mind explaining, there is just one line in `initState()` method which is `assert(...)`, so what's the benefit of even calling `super.initState()` in production app?

Comment: Thx a lot. Now it makes sense! So I guess to be on the safer side and for sake of good programming practice it's good to keep it at the beginning of the code.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot That means Flutter team is out of their mind by putting `mustCallSuper` in that method for more than 2 years now since Flutter came to existence. What's the benefit of putting it there sir?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Even if the team has created it for `mixin`, still there is going to be a single statement in this `initState` which is `assert(...)`, so what's the significance of even calling `super.initState()` for a production app?

Comment: `super.initState will call the initState method of all of your mixins in order` how can this be true for a production app when the whole code is going to be inside `assert`?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Just by mixing your sentences here and there won't help you scape. I am not sure whether you understand how `mixin` work in Dart, cause if you had, then you wouldn't  have written the responses like that. What's the meaning of putting a code in `assert`, it simply means something for debug version not for production, so even if I take your word that they are needed for `mixin` then in production mode, code inside `assert` won't work so how will a call to `super.initState()` have any impact there?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I would love to see an example of that `mixin`, and if you couldn't think of any, there is no benefit of writing something theoretical which according to you may be correct. It just misguides users.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Even I can create `mixins` the way you're talking about. But there is no evidence of your statements which you have posted in your answer, if you can share any official docs link of that, I'll be happy to upvote your post and will be in alignment with you. But you just thought of something and made it a fact without any proof.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I updated the answer accordingly to answer your questions and added an example of a framework mixin that executes logic in lifecycle methods.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Cool, I'll give it a look and let you know.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot So, `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` does call `super.initState` but I am not able to create a reproducible code to actually check if I really need a call to `super.initState` in it. Can you provide a sample?

Comment: @MattC That is exactly what the answer states.

Comment: what about super.didChangeDependencies()? Documentation is not clear about that but I assume it does not matter and depends on implementation... is that right?

Answer (score 26):

`super.initState()` should always be the first line in your `initState` method.

From docs:

> initState(): If you override this, make sure your method starts with a call to
>     super.initState().

Comment: Do you have the link to where you're quoting from in the docs? I think they changed to: wording to _"Implementations of this method should start with a call to the inherited method, as in super.initState()."_  [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)

Comment: @MendelG Yes, they updated the docs but the essence is same.

Answer (score 5):

As you could see in the classes from the framework, you should do everything after the widget is initialized, meaning after `super.initState()`.

I case of dispose would be logically in the other way, first do everything and then call `super.dispose()`.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // DO STUFF
}

@override
void dispose() {
  // DO STUFF
  super.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

initState called up by default whenever a new stateful widget is added into a widget tree. 
Now the super.initState performs the default implementation of the  base class of your widget.If you call anything before super.initState that depends on the base class then this might cause problem.
That's why it's recommended that you call initState in this fashion:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // DO STUFF
}
```

Comment: The reasoning is a bit flawed because for `dispose` it is the opposite. The framework expects you to call `super.dispose` **at the end**, but the recommendation is correct.

Comment: Because if you call super.dispose before disposing the other things then components that depends on your base class might clash.