# Flutter initState not working on physical device

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have an issue with an init. It is working on a iPhone simulator but not a physical device. What I mean, it is that on the physical device, not data is displayed. I do not understand why. FireBase is connected properly. If you could help, it would be great. Thank you.

```
@override
  void initState()  {

    _contextSelected = _context;

    getAllContextInFirebaseV1().then(( List<dynamic> allMyContexts) {
      setState(() {
        allContexts = allMyContexts.map((e) => MultiSelectItem(e, e)).toList();
      });
    });

    super.initState();
  }
```

```
Future <List<dynamic>>  getAllContextInFirebaseV1() async {

    CollectionReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users')
        .doc((FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid))
        .collection('contexts');

    QuerySnapshot contextsQuery = await ref.get();

    final allContexts = contextsQuery.docs.map((snap) => (snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['name']).toList();

    print (allContexts);

    return allContexts as List<dynamic>;
  }
```

```
///MultiSelect for Context
                  MultiSelectBottomSheetField(
                    key: _multiSelectKeyContext,
                    initialChildSize: 0.7,
                    maxChildSize: 0.95,
                    buttonIcon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward_outlined),
                    title: const Text("Context", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),),
                    buttonText: const Text(
                    "Choose Context", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),),
                    searchTextStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                    searchHintStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                    itemsTextStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                    items: allContexts,//TEST(), //allContexts,
                    searchable: true,
                    onConfirm: (valueContext) {
                      setState(() {
                        _contextSelected = valueContext;
                        contextSelected = valueContext;
                      });
                      _multiSelectKeyContext.currentState!.validate();
                    },
                    chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                      onTap: (dynamic item) {
                        setState(() {
                        });
                        _multiSelectKeyContext.currentState!.validate();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: I think you got initState issue, please read this thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400001/should-i-call-super-initstate-at-the-end-or-at-the-beginning

Comment: What physical device do you use Android/IOS?

Comment: @Jahidul Many thanks. I have modified my initState. Now it works also on the physical device.

Comment: @powerman23rus it is an iphone

Answer (score 0):

Don't use map.foreach use `for(var item in data){}` and then apply `setState((){})`

fix this

```
setState(() {
        allContexts = allMyContexts.map((e) => MultiSelectItem(e, e)).toList();
      });
```

by the `for(var e in allMyContexts){}`

If possible, do not use loops inside the initState and neither the map.foreach that cannot be expected