# ChangeNotifierProvider not updating the listener

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-change-notifier, changenotifier, flutter-change-notifier-provider

I have simplified my real app into the following code below to show the problem. I am basically trying to show the scroll offset of a list view on another widget (the real app is a lot more complex where the widget does other stuff with that offset).

I am returning the `ViewController()` as the body of my Scaffold in the `main.dart`. In my `ViewController` below, I have a stack which contains a `ListView` and a `Text`. I want the controller for the `ListView` to update the `Text` using the `ChangeNotifierProvider`. It doesn't work for some reason.

My `ChangeNotifier` is the `scrollProvider` which has been declared as a variable of the entire `ViewController` and I am passing the same `scrollProvider` into the `ChangeNotifierProvider` and also printing from the same.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ViewController extends StatefulWidget {
  const ViewController({super.key});

  @override
  State<ViewController> createState() => _ViewControllerState();
}

class _ViewControllerState extends State<ViewController> {
  final scrollController = ScrollController();
  final scrollProvider = ScrollProvider();

  @override
  void initState() {
    scrollController.addListener(scrollHandler);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollController.removeListener(scrollHandler);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void scrollHandler() {
    scrollProvider.setCurrentOffset(scrollController.offset);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        ListView.builder(
          controller: scrollController,
          itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
            return Text(
              "Index: $index",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
            );
          }),
          itemCount: 100,
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: CupertinoButton(
            onPressed: (() {}),
            child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: ((_) => scrollProvider),
              child: Text(
                "Offset: ${scrollProvider.currentOffset}",
                // "Offset: ${Provider.of<ScrollProvider>(context, listen: false).currentOffset}",
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 32,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ScrollProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  double? currentOffset;
  void setCurrentOffset(valueToSet) {
    if (currentOffset != valueToSet) {
      currentOffset = valueToSet;
      print("currentOffset: $currentOffset");
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care of two things:

1. If you want to create a provider from an already existing value, use the [ChangeNotifierProvider.value](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider/ChangeNotifierProvider.value.html) named constructor.
2. Wrap your `Text` widget into a `Consumer<ScrollProvider>` so that it gets notified when `currentOffset` is changed.

(And always call `super.initState` in `initState` in the first line and do your own logic afterwards.)

With some modifications in your code this is an example of how to get it working:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SafeArea(child: ViewController()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ViewController extends StatefulWidget {
  const ViewController({super.key});

  @override
  State<ViewController> createState() => _ViewControllerState();
}

class _ViewControllerState extends State<ViewController> {
  final scrollController = ScrollController();
  final scrollProvider = ScrollProvider();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController.addListener(scrollHandler);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollController.removeListener(scrollHandler);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void scrollHandler() {
    scrollProvider.setCurrentOffset(scrollController.offset);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        ListView.builder(
          controller: scrollController,
          itemBuilder: ((context, index) => Text(
                "Index: $index",
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
              )),
          itemCount: 100,
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: CupertinoButton(
            onPressed: (() {}),
            child: ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: scrollProvider,
              child: Consumer<ScrollProvider>(
                builder: (context, value, child) => Text(
                  "Offset: ${value.currentOffset}",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ScrollProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  double? currentOffset;
  void setCurrentOffset(valueToSet) {
    if (currentOffset != valueToSet) {
      currentOffset = valueToSet;
      print("currentOffset: $currentOffset");
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the comment about calling `super.initState` first, when I let VSCode autocomplete the `initState` function, it puts the `// TODO: implement initState` before the `super.initState`. So I thought my code goes before. I also saw a few example codes where the `super.initState` was at the end. Am I wrong?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html): "Implementations of this method should `start with` a call to the inherited method, as in super.initState().".

Comment: Also please refer to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400001/should-i-call-super-initstate-at-the-end-or-at-the-beginning).

Comment: Thanks. Good to know about the `initState` as well as the `dispose` one.