# What is the right way to perform tasks in override functions in Google flutter?

Tags: flutter

1. 

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    someFunctionCall();
}
```

2. 

```
@override
  void initState() {
    someFunctionCall();
    super.initState();
}
```

Which of the two is advisable on flutter?

Comment: Such a discussion has already been opened before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400001/should-i-call-super-initstate-at-the-end-or-at-the-beginning#:~:text=25-,super.,with% 20a%20call%20to%20super