# Understanding @mustCallSuper

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-analyzer

The [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/meta/mustCallSuper-constant.html) says implementations must call super. And there are even [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400001/should-i-call-super-initstate-at-the-end-or-at-the-beginning/58400324#58400324) about where to.

But I boldly did not call it on an annotated method (`State.initState`) I overrode (on flutter's `State`) and everything compiled and worked without any problem.

So, Is this implied by the compiler (or flutter tooling?) and super was called behind my back? Or does the static analyzer doesn't know how to enforce this?

Comment: Are you sure that `dart analyze`) (or `flutter analyze` for Flutter projects) did not report any warnings?  The static analyzer is separate from the compiler.  The analyzer should generate a warning, but it can't stop you from ignoring that warning and compiling and running anyway.

Comment: @jamesdlin you are correct. it is only a warning (`@shouldCallSuper`?) So i was missing it. Expected the "must" on the name would have broken compilation like using a wrong type.